# Serialize list of complex objects to JSON

Tags: c#, json, file-io, json.net

I can't figure out how to get Newtonsoft.Json to serialize this list:

```
var player = new List<ISprite>
    {
        new Sprite( head, position ),
        new Sprite( torso, position ),
        new Sprite( legs, position )
    };

fileParser.Write( "save.json", player );
```

The `Sprite` constructor takes two parameters: the first is the name of an asset and the second is a vector. `FileParser.Write` is defined as:

```
public void Write<T>( string fileName, T data )
{
    if ( string.IsNullOrEmpty( fileName ) )
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException();
    }

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( data );

    File.WriteAllText( fileName, json );
}
```

The file is created, but the result is always an array of empty objects:

```
[{},{},{}]
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Where is the definitin of *Sprite* ? Does it have any *public* property/field ?

Comment: I didn't realize they had to be public, duh. Although I'd rather not expose all the properties of my `Sprite` class.

Comment: Then add `[JsonProperty]` attribute to the private fields you want to serialize

Comment: Amazing. You should post that as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you don't have any public fields/properties in your Sprite class. A solution for this can be adding `[JsonProperty]` attribute to the private fields you want to serialize

Answer (score 0):

In fact your code is fine, it should work properly.
The thing is that maybe you are passing these Sprite instances empty to the json converter, are you assigning these values that you pass to constructor into the class properties, name and Vector?
what type of values are "head", "legs", "torso" and position, are these strings or objects.